# lwc refresh not working as expected

Tags: lightning-web-components, refreshapex

refreshApex isn't working for me. I'm calling it at the end of my submit and onsuccess functions but I guess I have it configured incorrectly. After I submit/save on the lightning-record-edit-form my table is empty. I refresh the browser and I see my changes. Does anyone know how to get this working?

html

```
            <template for:each={taskResourceList} for:item="mr">
                <div key={mr.Id} class="">
                    <lightning-record-edit-form 
                        record-id={mr.Id}
                        object-api-name="Mission_Resource__c" 
                        data-id={mr.Id}
                        onsuccess={handleSuccess} 
                        onerror={handleError} 
                        onsubmit={handleSubmit}>

                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-stretch slds-border_bottom slds-size_12-of-12">
                            <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_right">
                                <div class=" slds-m-right_medium slds-m-top_xxx-small slds-m-bottom_xxx-small">
                                    <lightning-input-field 
                                        variant="label-hidden" 
                                        onchange={handleChange} 
                                        data-id={mr.Id} 
                                        field-name="Status__c" 
                                        value={mr.Status__c}>
                                    </lightning-input-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
 . . . .
```

js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getTaskResources from '@salesforce/apex/RROSResourceListController.getTaskResources';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    
export default class RrosResourceTableForTaskDetail extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track taskResourceList;

    editTable = true;
    buttonVisible = false;

    @track productAnswerMap;

    taskResourceResults = null;

    @wire(getTaskResources, {taskId : '$recordId'})
    wiredResources(result) {
        this.taskResourceResults = result;
        if (result.data) {
            console.log('result.data ----  ', result.data);
            this.taskResourceList = result.data
        } else {
            console.log('result.error ----  ', result.error);
            this.error = result.error
        }
    }

    recordId;
    handleSuccess(event) {
        this.recordId = event.detail.id;
        const button = this.template.querySelector("lightning-button[data-id='" + this.recordId + "']");
        if (button) {
            button.classList.add("slds-hide");
        }

        const toast = new ShowToastEvent({
                                title: 'Updated',
                                message: 'Resource Updated Successfully!',
                                variant: 'success',
                                mode: 'dismissable'
                                });
        this.dispatchEvent(toast);

        return refreshApex(this.taskResourceResults);
    }
    
    handleSubmit(event) {
        let recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        console.log('--------handleSubmit--------', recordId);
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;

        fields.Quantity__c = Number(fields.Quantity__c) - Number(fields.Quantity_Filled__c);
        fields.Id = recordId;            
        this.template.querySelector("lightning-record-edit-form[data-id='" + recordId + "']").submit(fields);
        return refreshApex(this.taskResourceResults);

    }
. . . .
```

Comment: have you tried  decorating taskResourceResults   with track. although track is normally not required now it is still required  on objects/arrays  to make it reactive  to internal properties  and taskResourceResults     is nested object.  moreover  place html template code inside template if to make it lazy loaded only when  taskResourceList  is not empty

Comment: . moreover place html template @gaurav - code inside template if to make it lazy loaded

Can you explain this further?

Comment: <template for:each={taskResourceList} for:item="mr">.  you are iterating over taskResourceList   but  taskResourceList  will not alway have data  because wire will run mutiple times.  you only want to render your page  if  taskResourceList  have data  so check it in template:if   and dispaly accordingly.    did  track solved the issue?

Comment: why are you returning refreshApex?

Comment: idk - going from an example @NickCook

Comment: track didn't solve my issue @gauravsharma

Answer (score 1):

The `refreshApex` function should be called after updating the data in the database. In your code, you are calling `refreshApex` in both the `handleSuccess` and `handleSubmit` functions, but there is no guarantee that the data will have been updated in the database at that point.

You can move the `refreshApex` call to the end of the `handleSuccess` function, as this function is triggered only after the record is successfully saved to the database.

Here's the updated code:

```js
handleSuccess(event) {
  this.recordId = event.detail.id;
  const button = this.template.querySelector("lightning-button[data-id='" + this.recordId + "']");
  if (button) {
    button.classList.add("slds-hide");
  }

  const toast = new ShowToastEvent({
    title: 'Updated',
    message: 'Resource Updated Successfully!',
    variant: 'success',
    mode: 'dismissable'
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(toast);

  refreshApex(this.taskResourceResults);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  let recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  console.log('--------handleSubmit--------', recordId);
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
  const fields = event.detail.fields;

  fields.Quantity__c = Number(fields.Quantity__c) - Number(fields.Quantity_Filled__c);
  fields.Id = recordId;            
  this.template.querySelector("lightning-record-edit-form[data-id='" + recordId + "']").submit(fields);
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't the refreshApex in mackmama's handleSuccess function still worked?

Comment: I ended up calling the function directly, removing wire, and calling it directly onsuccess